# Error interval RXJS/react-native (redux-observable)

Tags: react-native, rxjs, redux-observable

Error "undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ajax.ajax.getJSON(getIntervalUrl(response)).interval(10000)')";

```
export const chartOneDayEpic = action$ => action$.ofType(FETCHING_CHART_DATA_ONE_DAY)
  .mergeMap(action => ajax.getJSON(getChartOneDayUrl(action))
    .timeout(10000)
    .retry(3)
    .switchMap(response => ajax.getJSON(getIntervalUrl(response))
      .interval(10000)
      .timeInterval()
      .map(intervalDataResponse => fetchChartDataSuccess(response.concat(intervalDataResponse)))
      .catch(err => Observable.of(fetchChartDataFailure(err))
     )
    )
  );
```

It mean the ajax.getJSON doesn't have the .interval function, and i don't know why , any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

[`interval`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) is a **static** operator factory--it is only available at `Observable.interval(time)`, not on instances of Observables. That's because it actually creates an Observable that itself produces an incrementing value at that interval, so it doesn't make sense as an instance operator because it would be be ignoring the source you applied to to.

> interval returns an Observable that emits an infinite sequence of ascending integers, with a constant interval of time of your choosing between those emissions. The first emission is not sent immediately, but only after the first period has passed.